# Logrotate not picking up or acting on new configuration file

Tags: bash, cron, configuration, logrotate

I had a `logrotate` configuration file set up for a log (let's call it *Log1*). It is working fine and the log is rotating everyday as expected.

Yesterday I cloned this set up and modified it for three more log files *Log2, Log3 and Log4*. These log files already exist on disk, and are being actively written to.

However, when checked today, the three log files did not rotate at all. I was expecting them to rotate along with the first log file *Log1*. But only *Log1* was rotated, and the rest (*Log2* to *Log4*) weren't touched at all.

If I place new configuration files for `logrotate`, **do I have to run a command to "activate" them so `logrotate` will start rotating the log files?** I thought since it's a `cron` job running at 4 am everyday, it will automatically pick up the new files and rotate files. Is there some sort of manual activation needed?

What's strange is that the `/var/lib/logrotate.status` file seems to show (with today's date) that **all four** log files were looked at by `logrotate`. So, why did `logrotate` skip the three new log files that obviously need rotating?

---

**Configuration file:**

```
/path/to/Log1.log {
    compress
    compresscmd /usr/bin/bzip2
    compressext .bz2
    compressoptions -9
    copytruncate
    daily
    dateext
    delaycompress
    extension .log
    notifempty
    missingok
    nomail
    olddir Log1
    rotate 100
    maxage 60
}
```

There shouldn't be anything wrong with the configuration file, since it works fine for *Log1*. The `olddir` directory is already created for all the logs.

When running `logrotate -d` (debug mode), it says `log does not need rotating` for all four logs. I understand this is correct for `Log1` since it's already rotated, but what about the others?

Does it have anything to do with `after 1 days`? Does `logrotate` first mark the new file's date in `logrotate.status` file, then only rotate when one day has elapsed since the last mark? **How is the status file used by `logrotate`?**

Comment: Does `logrotate -d` (debug mode) show anything enlightening? Maybe there's one more place you need to change the filename in the config file (I'm sure this not only happens to me?). `logrotate` runs with high privileges, so there shouldn't be permissions issues, like being unable to read/create the files, but double-checking can't hurt.

Comment: It says `log does not need rotating` for all four logs. I understand this is correct for *Log1* since it's already rotated, but what about the others? **Also,** all owners, groups, rights are exactly the same for all four log files and related files/directories.

Comment: Please include your logrotate config file for one of the failed rotations in the question.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with `after 1 days`? Does `logrotate` first mark the new file date's in `logrotate.status` file, then only rotate when one day has elapsed since the last mark? **How is the status file used by `logrotate`?**

Comment: Do you have a `minsize` setting in the logrotate configuration? If the new files haven't reached that size they won't be rotated.

Comment: Updated question. @Barmar No such setting. Besides, one of the log files not rotated is in the hundreds of MB.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `logrotate` works using the `logrotate.status` file. In this status file, the log's modified date is marked down. The rotation only kicks in once the modified date of the log file changes from the marked date by a given delta (usually 1 day).

The status file is used by `logrotate` to avoid rotating a log file multiple times before the delta time has elapsed. Although I would reckon there's no harm in starting to rotate a file that is not yet marked in the status file and simply marking it fresh afterwards, I do not know why `logrotate` did not adopt this strategy.

*If anyone provides a more substantial and detailed answer describing the above and explaining the reasons for it, I will accept your answer.*